# changing height of an embedded element on different page based on user input

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to embed a smart search-bar as an iframe/embeded/object or similar element (open for suggestions). The core issue I'm facing is that the height of the element doesn't adjusts based on user input (limit unnecessary white space at the bottom/cutting off data).

**IMPORTANT NOTE: The search-bar and the site who display the search-bar are located on different origins**.

**example for clarification:**

my current HTML code:

```
<embed type="text/html"
       src="http://search-bar.com"
       height="550px" // DEFINED A FIXED HEIGHT ONLY FOR THE EXAMPLE 
       style="outline: 1px solid red;">
```

I want the outline of the search-bar results to match the height of the element (marked in blue) instead of being fixed as it now (which creates white space/cuts off data).

[image]

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

Please advise, sweet internet!

Comment: it's not easy probably not possible due to browser's policy for the different origins

Comment: What would you do if you had to crack it? I'm open to suggestions..

Comment: Would hack the browser and crack open it  while inserting the code : )

Comment: @mor2778 i did it about 10-12 years ago... but newly you can't do it for different origins... unless they open their origin for your changes !!!

Comment: I believe they can open me the origin for my changes (unless its a bad practice from security perspective that I'm not aware of)

Comment: should I use  <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="http://search-bar.com"> for it?